How can I disassemble a whole obj file in valid asm, amend some sections of such asm code and reassemble to obj?
Is it possible on Linux to use objdump (or any other utility) to fully disassemble an obj file to asm code, modify such code and then pass the asm to as?
The challenge I have with objdump is that it doesn't disassemble all sections by default and interleaves descriptions/strings that can't be interpreted/ignored by as.
How can I efficiently do:

Get valid asm from an obj file
Modifiy such asm
re-run as to generate a valid obj file

Again, I don't need to 'study' the asm (objdump is fine for that), I need a valid asm that I can modify and feed back to as.
Thanks!

Near duplicate of How to disassemble, modify and then reassemble a Linux executable? , although easier since you have just an object file.  Agner Fog's objconv can produce asm ready to assemble, with labels for branch targets.  Unlike objdump which just makes a listing.  But getting .data / .rodata / .bss correct could still be a challenge, IDK how well it does with that.

Is there in the open source world/GNU toolchains to be able to do the same? Find it weird that no-one else has has similar requirements so far?

https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv is open source, GPLed.

Would it get those segments .data ... correct as you mentioned?

I think so, been a while since I used it.  It's a useful disassembler and easy to use; give it a try.  objconv -fgasm to disassemble into "GAS" syntax, as opposed to -fnasm or -fmasm.
